# Why can't I use ParticleSystem.Emit() outside of Start() method?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am trying to use `ParticleSystem.Emit()` to dynamically emit particles, and am unable to get `Emit()` to work outside of the `Start()` method.

I am able to emit particles in the `Start()` method, either directly or with a separate method. When attempting to do the same in `Update()`, `LateUpdate()`, or `FixedUpdate()` it no longer works.

There are no errors reported. I reported the number of particles in the update methods to make sure that the code there was actually running, and it reports however many particles I emit in the `Start()` method.

When trying to emit particles in the update methods I have tried:

1. Using `Emit()` directly in the update loop.
2. Using a separate method called directly in the update loop.
3. Using a separate method called using `Invoke()` in the update loop.

I'm able to check and alter particle position in `Update()`, so I don't think I'm having some kind of scope problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystem aSystem;
    private ParticleSystem.Particle[] aParticle;

    void Start()
    {
        aParticle = new ParticleSystem.Particle[aSystem.main.maxParticles];

        // Emit particle.
        DoEmit();

        Debug.Log("Particle Count: " + aSystem.particleCount);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        int numParticles = aSystem.GetParticles(aParticle);
        Debug.Log("Number of particles: " + numParticles);
        for (int i = 0; i < numParticles; i++)
        {
            if (aParticle[i].position.z > 1)
            {
                aParticle[i].position = new Vector3(0f,0f,0f);
            }
            aParticle[i].velocity = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f);
        }
        aSystem.SetParticles(aParticle);

        // Emit particle.
        DoEmit();
    }

    void DoEmit()
    {
        // Configure render settings for particle.
        ParticleSystemRenderer aRenderer = aSystem.GetComponent<ParticleSystemRenderer>();
        aRenderer.renderMode = ParticleSystemRenderMode.Mesh;
        aRenderer.mesh = Resources.Load<Mesh>("vector");

        // Configure rest of settings and emit.
        var emitParams = new ParticleSystem.EmitParams();
        emitParams.startLifetime = 120;
        emitParams.position = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        emitParams.velocity = new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        emitParams.startSize = 1;
        aSystem.Emit(emitParams, 1);
        aSystem.Play(); // Continue normal emissions
        Debug.Log("DoEmit() called!");
    }
}
```

Expected result: A stream of particles moving in the +z direction.

Actual result: One particle moving in the +z direction.

Comment: did you try it without the `aSystem.Play();`? Not sure but maybe it is restarting the particle system every frame?

Comment: @derHugo Yeah, I tried commenting out `aSystem.Play()`. I also tried shifting aSystem.Play() out of the DoEmit() method. Neither of those things worked.

It's possible that the particle system is restarting, I'd think it would be obvious to see though since my particles are created at the origin and my particles are allowed to travel a distance over several frames. Can you think of any better way to test than just watching the vectors on the Game window?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar and found [this answer in the Unity forums](http://answers.unity.com/answers/1573665/view.html) gave me a great, reliable solution that I've reused and modified to my purposes many times. It's a particle pool from which you can emit one or more particles as needed, killing off the last particle made and reusing it once it reaches its max number of particles. I think it achieves exactly what you're looking for. I'll include the relevant script here for reference (complete with [@Artifact-Jesse](https://answers.unity.com/users/139276/artifactjesse.html)'s colorful commentary for clarity).

Note that this script was written for Unity 2018.x, but still works great as of 2020.2.1

Artifact-Jesse's complete, functional example of a fairly generic particle pool:

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(ParticleSystem))]
public class ParticlePool : MonoBehaviour
{

 private int lastParticleIndex = 0;  // keeps track of our oldest particle (for deletion)

 // these will all be inited in Initialize() on Start()
 private ParticleSystem particleSys;             // our object's particle system
 private ParticleSystem.Particle[] particles;    // our reusable array of particles
 private ParticleSystem.EmitParams emitParams;   // reusable emitparams
 private int maxParticles = 0;       // total number of particles in our scene before re-using


 private void Awake()
 {
     Initialize(); // initialize all of our member variables
 }



 public void CreateParticle(Vector3 position, float size, Vector3 velocity, float angularVelocity)
 {
     // if we're at our particle count limit, kill our oldest particle.

     int activeParticles = particleSys.GetParticles(particles);
     /// this thing sucks. Read the Unity docs VERY carefully to understand...
     /// basically the parameter (particles) is an out parameter which will
     /// write out the existing particles in the particle system to our
     /// reusable array. After that, we can directly modify the particles
     /// and then when we're done, write the particles back into the
     /// particle system with ParticleSystem.SetParticles( particles, count )
     
     if (activeParticles >= maxParticles)
     {
         // set lifetime to -1 to kill the particle
         particles[lastParticleIndex].remainingLifetime = -1;
         // we need to reset start lifetime to a normal value, too or the particle will still have infinite lifetime
         particles[lastParticleIndex].startLifetime = 1;

         lastParticleIndex++;    // keep track of oldest particle
         if (lastParticleIndex >= maxParticles) lastParticleIndex = 0;

         // have to re-write
         particleSys.SetParticles(particles, particles.Length);  // write those pesky particles back into our ParticleSystem
     }


     // set up params for this particle, you can use whatever you want (see unity docs for EmitParams for what's available)
     emitParams.angularVelocity = angularVelocity;
     emitParams.position = position;
     emitParams.startSize = size;
     emitParams.velocity = velocity;
     emitParams.startLifetime = float.MaxValue; // float.MaxValue makes the particle's lifetime infinite

     particleSys.Emit(emitParams, 1);
     particleSys.Play();
 }


 void Initialize()
 {
     if (particleSys == null)
         particleSys = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

     maxParticles = particleSys.main.maxParticles;

     if (particles == null || particles.Length < particleSys.main.maxParticles)
         particles = new ParticleSystem.Particle[particleSys.main.maxParticles];
 }
```

}

**Note:** the particle system in this example is just bare mininum with a renderer. Not looping, no start on awake, simulation space set to World. MaxParticles is respected by the above script.